# What is the function of ものな in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

これは冷やして食べるものなのですか

I did some searching but nothing seemed to quite explain what I'm looking for.

I'm assuming the second の is the explanatory の, but what is ものな? Are the もの and な separate? They feel that way to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If it had been written as:

> これは冷やして食べるものだ

would it have made sense to you?

> これは冷やして食べるものだ

means "this is something to eat cold."  But generally, Japanese is pretty explicit about how information is being conveyed in a way which is alien to English.  When giving an *explanation*  or asking for *clarification* the Japanese will indicate this by tacking

> のです

to the end.  Here the speaker is asking for clarification, so

> のですか

is tacked onto the end.

However, "の" is a nominalizer which means before it だ needs to be changed to な

> これは冷やして食べるものだ + のですか

becomes

> これは冷やして食べるものなのですか

Which in English just translates to "Is this something something to eat cold?"  In English, the nuance of のですか is completely lost.

Comment: Thanks. I think my confusion is coming from the fact that my understanding of the meaning of the sentence was "is this usually eaten cold?" I didn't realize "something" was involved and was trying to figure out what a V+もの construction did. So it's really just "something that gets eaten" plus and explanatory "の"?

Comment: Could you please link me something about this rule? "However, "の" is a nominalizer which means before it だ needs to be changed to な"

Comment: @charlemagne In your sentence, もの before なのだ is just "(some)thing", and 食べるもの is more like "something which one eats" rather than "something that gets eaten", since there is no passive verb. 冷やして食べるもの is literally "something which one refrigerates and (then) eats", thus "something to eat cold". A very literal translation would be "Is it that this is something which one refrigerates and (then) eats?"

Comment: Thanks everyone.